# Scraping values from table with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some historical weather data and can't figure out how  to extract values from a table. I've been able to print the rows within the table, but when I attempt to extract 'td' (more specifically the values) from each row, I get an attribute error. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from random import choice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KORD/2017/4/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=10&monthend=4&yearend=2017&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo="
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
table = soup.find('table', id='obsTable')

table_head = table.find('thead')
header_1 = []    
for th in table_head.find_all('th'):
    key_1 = th.get_text()
    header_1.append(key_1)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
table_head_2 = table.find_all('tr')[1]
header_2 = []
for td in table_head_2.find_all('td'):
    key_2 = td.get_text()
    header_2.append(key_2)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#    
rows = table.find_all('tr')[2]

for row in rows.find_all('td'):
    print(row)
```

This is returned when I print a single row of the data:

```
<tr>
<td><a href="/history/airport/KORD/2017/4/1/DailyHistory.html">1</a></td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">59</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">47</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">34</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">31</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">23</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">16</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">82</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">51</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">20</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">30.24</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">30.19</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">30.09</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">10</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">10</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">10</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">13</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">6</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">17</span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="wx-value">0.00</span>
</td>
<td>
     
</td>
</tr>
```

If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it.

Comment: print(row.text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to print the values, this can be accomplished by calling the `.text` attribute of `row`. However, there is a lot of whitespace around the values, so you will want to `strip()` them.

```
for row in rows.find_all('td'):
    print(row.text.strip())
```

will return:

```
1
59
47
34
31
23
16
82
51
20
30.24
30.19
30.09
10
10
10
13
6
17
0.00
```